# Visual Studio 2012 VisualSVN: add solution file to Subversion manually (website project)

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I created a Website project in Visual Studio 2012. It saved the `*sln` file in a different folder (`..Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebSite1`) while the other files are under (`..Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite1`). I added the files under `WebSites` folder in subversion but how I can add the `*.sln` file manually in the same subversion so another user can get and build this project?

Comment: Re-create the website project per https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00002/

Comment: @bahrep it doesnt help. If I follow it Visual Studio 2012 creates 2 projects under the solution one with the website's files and one with the *.sln file